# Submit POST form from url

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

Website: www.example.com

```
<form method="POSt" action="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="test1"  value="test11" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test2"  value="" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="test3"  value="test33" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to sumbit this form with adding the correct parameters in the URL. With GET, I can simply use : `http://ww.example.com/?test1=test11&test2=&test3=test33` and the form will be sumbitted. Can I do the same for a POST? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: `POST` means that form values will be passed in on the headers. If you pass them on the URL it is not a `POST`.

Comment: I see, is it possible to sent a header with the correct data somehow?

Comment: Um. That way you posted will do that. That's how it works.

Comment: This is a good question. SO mods fail again.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send `POST` parameters from the `URL` as they are sent in the `header`.

Form:

```
<form method="POSt" action="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="test1"  value="test11" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test2"  value="" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="test3"  value="test33" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Once the form is submitted you can retrieve these values on the next page easily like this:

```
<?php echo $_POST["test1"]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST["test2"]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST["test3"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery ajax POST like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ww.example.com/',
            data: { test1: $('#test1').val(), test2: $('#test2').val(), test3: $('#test3').val() },
            success: function (response) { alert(respone); },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
        });
```

but it will not sent in query string because POST does not sent data in URL, it is use to send securely data to server like Password etc.